# Need Assistance with my Encryption Program

Tags: python, python-2.7

Instructions:

Edit: I just need the Method Menu to return "coming soon" since - as it stands currently, if the user inputs, c, p, or s it returns nothing. I don't see the logical reason why.

```
def PrintDescription():
    print 'This program encrypts and descrypts messages using multiple \
encryption methods.\nInput files must be in the same directory as this program.\
\nOutput files will be created in this same directory.'

def StartMenu():
    print 'Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt?'
    print '<e>ncrypt'
    print '<d>ecrypt'
    print '<q>uit'

def MethodMenu():
  print 'Which method would you like to use?'
  print '<c>aesarian fixed offset'
  print '<p>seudo-random offset'
  print '<s>ubstitution cipher'
  a = raw_input("")
  while a not in ('c', 'p', 's'):
    if a:
      print "Error: You must type c, p, or s"
      a = raw_input("")
    if a == 'c' or a=='p' or a=='s':
      print 'Coming Soon'         

def main():
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.?! \t\n\r"
    PrintDescription()
    a = None
    while a not in ('e', 'd', 'q'):
        if a:
            print "Error: You must type e, d, or q"
        else:
            StartMenu()
        a = raw_input("")
        if a == 'e' or a=='d':
          MethodMenu()
        if a == 'q':
          break  

main()
```

Comment: Have you run this in a debugger? [PDB](http://sontek.net/blog/detail/debugging-python-with-pdb) comes with python, or you can use something like [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) if you want something graphical.

Comment: I haven't. This is a school assignment. I'm pretty new to python.

Comment: Double check which block the if statement you're checking for `a` 'c' 'p' or 's' is in.

Comment: I don't get it? It's under the while loop. What do I need to do?

Comment: What happens when your while loop checks `a not in ('c', 'p', 's')` if the command is valid the first time around? (Hint, your program works if you type an *invalid* command before trying to type a good one)

Comment: I don't know - I mean I have an if statement that is supposed to check for c, p, and s. I don't understand why it will return blank. The if a: does not. What gives?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26761/discussion-between-jodi-peterson-and-collin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few comments, before I present my solution.

1. The MethodMenu() function currently does not return anything. I think you meant to return the user's choice.
2. I see a pattern between the StartMenu() and MethodMenu(): each displays a list of choice and repeatedly getting the user's input until the user enters the correct input. However, the StartMenu() function does not manage the user's input, while the MethodMenu() does ==> inconsistency in design.
3. Since the act of getting the user's input and validate it happens twice, it is a good idea to move that block of code into a separate function which you can call instead of writing the same block of code more than once.
4. I notice the user of single-letter variable *a*. I general, I advice to use more descriptive names such as *user_choice*, *user_answer*, or *user_input*.

Without further ado, my solution:

```
def PrintDescription():
    print 'This program encrypts and descrypts messages using multiple \
encryption methods.\nInput files must be in the same directory as this program.\
\nOutput files will be created in this same directory.'

def GetChoice(acceptable_answers):
    while True:
        user_choice = raw_input('')
        if user_choice in acceptable_answers:
            return user_choice
        else:
            print 'Please try:', ', '.join(acceptable_answers)

def StartMenu():
    print 'Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt?'
    print '<e>ncrypt'
    print '<d>ecrypt'
    print '<q>uit'
    user_choice = GetChoice('edq')
    return user_choice

def MethodMenu():
    print 'Which method would you like to use?'
    print '<c>aesarian fixed offset'
    print '<p>seudo-random offset'
    print '<s>ubstitution cipher'
    user_choice = GetChoice('cps')
    return user_choice

def main():
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.?! \t\n\r"
    PrintDescription()

    while True:
        user_choice = StartMenu()
        if user_choice in ('e', 'd'):
            user_choice = MethodMenu()
            # Do something based on the user_choice
        if user_choice == 'q':
            break

main()
```

#### Update

If you must know what is wrong with `MethodMenu()`, here is the explanation: The user typed the correct choice (c, p, or s) the first time: the whole while loop is skipped, that means 'Coming Soon' will not be printed. You can either revise your solution, or go with *hek2mgl's*.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Hai. That's a very advanced way of doing this program to me - I'll have to study it a little bit. In the mean time - I'd still like to solve my current problem. It just bugs me because I don't understand why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Following you logic you should change the function `MethodMenu()` to:

```
def MethodMenu():
  print 'Which method would you like to use?'
  print '<c>aesarian fixed offset'
  print '<p>seudo-random offset'
  print '<s>ubstitution cipher'
  a = None
  while a not in ('c', 'p', 's'):
    if a:
      print "Error: You must type c, p, or s"
    a = raw_input("")
    if a == 'c' or a=='p' or a=='s':
      print 'Coming Soon'
```

But why using `a` instead of `user_input` or something else?! you should use expressive variable names! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, when I tried using this code it loops the print: Error: indefinitely. Do you know how to fix this?